How to get the 20-year-anniversary themes and sounds in Ubuntu 24.04?
Ubuntu 24.10 will feature a Warty brown theme, wallpaper and a special login sound to celebrate the 20-year-anniversary of Ubuntu. Check out this article for more details. The article calls these Easter Eggs because they are not the default theme/sounds, but need to be configured from the settings.
I don't want to upgrade to the non-LTS version, but I would like to try these "Easter Eggs".
How to install/load them in Ubuntu 24.04?
Is there a package I can install from the 24.10 repositories? Is there a shell script to load these?
Please note: I am looking for the 20-year-anniversary specific "easter eggs", and not the generic ones (like APT's super cow powers).

I have described the features I want. And I want to install them in 24.04. I don't see why it is not on topic

Are you asking about This? It mostly it consists of terminal commands, I seen several others not listed here .

In addition, Here are some humorous things you can add to your system to spice things up: Where are sudo's insults stored?, The Python Error Steamroller and my personal favorite - fortune to  include offensive fortunes. See fortune manpage to exclude a  particular  set  of  fortunes.

I voted to reopen the question given 24.10 is released. None of these comments address the 24.10 specific Easter Eggs I am looking for.

@muru I added a source

In my question I mentioned what I mean by "Easter Eggs". Calling these themes/sounds by a different name doesn't change what they are. I don't see the point of arguing here. If you can come up with a better keyword to describe the question, please feel free to edit it.

I updated the question again

That is better - still multiple things in one, but at least clearly defined. Voted to reopen.

In case it gets reopened, the yaru-theme-gnome-shell and yaru-theme-sound have files mentioning warty, so those seem to be the relevant packages to try installing. The sound theme might be OK to install directly, but GNOME changes too much for the theme package to be safe.
